# There is no such thing as a Fortran compiler?

Tags: c, compilation, fortran

One of my professors told me last night that "there is no such thing as a Fortran compiler" and that when one compiles Fortran what actually happens is that it is converted to C and then it is compiled in C.

This seems a little off to me as Fortran was invented in 1957 and C in 1972. Does he mean modern Fortran compilers used today such as GNU and Intel?

Comment: Not that all compilers do so, but converting Fortran to C is _compiling_ Fortran.

Comment: Lots of compilers these days translate to intermediate representations. Programs that translate Fortran syntax to C are Fortran compilers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are plenty of Fortran compilers that don't use C as an intermediate representation. Some examples are the compilers from Intel and Portland Group, and the gnu compiler gfortran. The NAG Fortran compiler converts to C and then compiles that (I'm pretty sure this is still true), and early on before the first "true" gnu Fortran compiler you had to use f2c (long, long deprecated), but these are the only such case I've come across in almost 3 decades of using Fortran.

Comment: In the past there were also Fortran compilers such as those from HP which didn't  use a C intermediate code representation but did apply some C translation rules (e.g. strict left-to-right, or shortcut evaluation) which were different from Fortran.  It is common for companion C and Fortran processors to share a common intermediate language and back end.

Comment: "Different from Fortran" is might cause a little confusion. I think I would say "more strict than the Fortran standard actually requires".